# Why won't the CMD window close after Batch file execution?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to execute a file by placing the appropriate command into a batch file. After completing the file execution the command window is not closing automatically. I tried it with the Exit command too but it is not closing the window automatically.

The command in my batch file:

```
start "" /w /B /d "%CD%\Project-Aug-New\MyCardApi\trunk\src\build\bin" MyCardApiTest_32d.exe
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `/b` (and the `/w`) from the start command.  The `/b` starts the program in the same window and the `/w` keeps the window open until the program terminates.

Comment: I removed /b and /w ,still it is not closing the window automatically. Either i need to close manually or pressing the enter button is closing the window.

Comment: The window you are talking about now is the program window - not the cmd window.  `Autoit` can press buttons and click in program windows.

Answer (score 2):

The `/w` parameter makes `START` wait until the process it launches has exited. Remove it:

```
start "" /B /d ...
```

This will let your batch file continue running and exit immediately.

Comment: still it is not closing the window automatically. Either i need to close manually or pressing the enter button is closing the window.

Comment: @123r789: The code that calls the batch file is responsible for that. How do you run it?

Comment: Directly by double click the batch file.

Comment: @123r789: Works fine for me. I created a batch file with `start "" /b notepad`. When I double click it notepad starts and no command prompt remains open.

Answer (score 0):

the below worked for me (use both):

```
exit
goto :EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

You can close the console at the end

For example:

```
   start /b taskkill /F /IM bank01.exe
   ..
   ..
   taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe
```