# Exit windows terminal interactive mode from within a script

Tags: python, batch-file, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

The setup is something like this:

- init.bat does some stuff and then calls `python app.py -i`.
- app.py is the core of the program and depending on user input, it may end up running all sort of programs on the terminal.
- Most commands are meant to end with a way for the user to continue entering commands, but there are others which I want to close the terminal after doing their tasks.

---

Example:

User enters a command:    `>>> dostuff` which is meant to close the terminal after finishing.

app.py processes it:

```
def dostuff():
    #here's the issue.
    #i want it to run a program and close the terminal
    #but since it's on interactive mode, it will stay open after processing the command.
    print('doing some stuff')
    os.system('.\stuff.bat')
    # exits...
```

stuff.bat:

```
@echo i'm gonna do some stuff and close the terminal
rem ...stuff
rem ...stuff
:: exits...
```

At this point, the terminal should be closed, but the interactive mode prevents that from happening.

---

I hope my explanation is clear. What I need is a way to force the program to run-and-quit after certain commands, or for a way to toogle interactive mode on/off without exiting the program that is currently being executed, but I'm not sure about how to implement that after setting the terminal to interactive mode.

Comment: Have you tried `exit()`?

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the issue. Both `exit()` (in the .py file) and `exit` (.bat file) are implicit there. 

The terminal closes as expected if I don't start app.py in interactive mode, but I'm looking for a way to start it on that mode, yet force it to exit on some scenarios.

If it's not possible, I think it will be simple enough to code it the other way around: defaulting it to exit and forcing it to go interactive on some scenarios, but I'd rather not do it that way, since what I'm currently attempting looks cleaner to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the CMD window will not close after Batch file execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738490/why-the-cmd-window-will-not-close-after-batch-file-execution)

Comment: Might be related: http://superuser.com/questions/192550/why-wont-cmd-exit-after-execution-of-batch-file

Comment: Thanks for the links, but it's not a duplicate. I know that the interactive mode is causing it, and I'm explicitly telling it to run on interactive mode. What I need is a way to turn it off whenever I want to.

Comment: if I create the function in my .py file and write `exit()` command inside this function, invoking this function in interpreter mode makes it close the interpreter. Isn't this the thing you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes. But it won't work if the terminal is on interactive mode, which is what i'm trying to toogle from within the script.

Comment: Use `raise SystemExit` to exit interactive mode, programatically

Comment: `raise SystemExit`, `sys.exit()`, `os._exit()`, etc. only send the terminal from "python mode" to "cmd mode".

Comment: Execute `exit` command _with NO /B switch_ in the stuff.bat file. The _implicit exit_ here may be executed as `exit /B` that does NOT close the cmd session; this depends on the way that phyton uses to run the Batch file (with or without /K switch).

Comment: @aacini - I think STUFF will run in its own cmd.exe context, so even when it exits (and then python exits), the parent interactive cmd.exe that called python will still be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can control the exit code that python returns.

Simply have python return 0 if you want to continue, or 1 if you want to exit. Then modify the call to python within INIT.BAT as follows:

```
python app.py -i || exit
```